# Elastic Cloud APM Server - Queue is full

Tags: apm, elastic-cloud

I have many Java microservices running in a Kubernetes Cluster. All of them are APM agents sending data to an APM server in our Elastic Cloud Cluster.

Everything was working fine but suddenly every microservice received the error below showed in the logs.

[image]

I tried to restart the cluster, increase the hardware power and I tried to follow the [hints](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/6.3/tune-apm-server.html#tune-output-config) but no success.

Obs: The disk is almost empty and the memory usage is ok.
Everything is in 7.5.2 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all the indexes related to APM and everything worked after some minutes.

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: Using Kibana interface.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/reduce-apm-storage.html#delete-data-in-kibana

Answer (score 1):

> for better performance u can fine tune these fields in apm-server.yml file

1. internal queue size increase `queue.mem.events=output.elasticsearch.worker * output.elasticsearch.bulk_max_size`
   default is 4096
2. output.elasticsearch.worker (increase) default is 1
3. output.elasticsearch.bulk_max_size (increase) default is 50 very less

> Example : for my use case i have used following stats for 2 apm-server nodes and 3 es nodes (1 master 2 data nodes )

```yaml
queue.mem.events=40000
output.elasticsearch.worker=4
output.elasticsearch.bulk_max_size=10000
```